# Double-Click URL to Follow in Microsoft Excel 2003?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2003

I want to automatically follow a hyperlinked cell when double-clicked, not single-clicked.

Can I configure this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure - No.

You wold have to code somthing to emulate a hyperlink, perhaps using the `BeforeDoubleClick` event